# Show that $\frac {a^n - b^n} {a-b} = a^{n-1}b^0 + a^{n-2}b^1 ... + a^1b^{n-2}+a^0b^{n-1}$ for $a \neq b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a proof of the complex derivative of the complex function $f(z) = z^n$, I am presented with an equality :

$\frac {a^n - b^n} {a-b} = a^{n-1}b^0 + a^{n-2}b^1 ... + a^1b^{n-2}+a^0b^{n-1}$ for $a \neq b$ where the author says to prove this equality by induction on the integer value $n$.

Ignoring the inductive step suppose that $\frac {a^n - b^n} {a-b} = a^{n-1}b^0 + ... + a^0b^{n-1}$. I do not have any ideas how to proceed other than to write
$(a^n+b^n) = (a^{n/2} - b^{n/2} )(a^{n/2} + b^{n/2} )$. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: "Without" induction (there is some implicit induction like with almost any proof ever): Multiply both sides by $a-b$ and see what happens to the right-hand side.

Comment: @Arthur a telescoping sum giving the numerator.

Comment: And thus it is proven.

Comment: The standard hint for proving $a-b$ divides $a^n-b^n$ using induction says $a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}= a(a^k-b^k)+b^k(a-b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a high-school identity, which relies on the fundamental identity:
$$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$$
which is the simplest non-trivial example of induction one can show to beginners.

To obtain your identity, set $x=\dfrac ba$ and rewrite
$$a^n-b^n=a^n\biggl(1-\Bigl(\frac ba\Bigr)^n\biggr)=a^n(1-x^n).$$